# how can i push to my repository on github in eclipse application

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I cloned a github repository on eclipse. i can pull from github server, i could not push to origin on github server. eclipse gives an error as authentication does not support. i use https protocol. i do not write port number on eclipse configuration.

i configure my repository as below.

[image: github repository]

and then i click save and push.

[image: save and push]

and then eclipse gives error.

[image]

how can i resolve this problem ? thank you very much.